# Check differences in Postgres STATEMENT Triggers

Tags: postgresql, performance, triggers

I have a trigger that should insert on a table the records that were changed on another table. The table that is being changed could be updated on a massive way so we decided to use statement triggers for performance.

To check if the update changed any records, on the trigger function we are joining the "old" table and the "new" table, but this results on a inefficient plan.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_update_det
    AFTER UPDATE ON test_table
    REFERENCING
        NEW TABLE AS new_table
        OLD TABLE AS old_table
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_trigger();

--trigger on update:
INSERT INTO lima_four (quebec, a, b, c,d)
            SELECT DISTINCT ON (alpha.victor, alpha.kilo_tango) 
                two.quebec,
                alpha.kilo_tango,
                alpha.victor,
                two.november_two,
                ARRAY['price'] :: TEXT[]
            FROM new_table two --new_table two
            INNER JOIN old_table papa ON two.november_two = papa.november_two AND two.november_romeo = papa.november_romeo
            INNER JOIN oscar_quebec alpha ON two.quebec = alpha.quebec AND two.zulu = alpha.zulu
            WHERE   
                    (   two.sierra five DISTINCT FROM papa.sierra
                    OR  two.tango_delta five DISTINCT FROM papa.tango_delta
                    OR  two.yankee_foxtrot five DISTINCT FROM papa.yankee_foxtrot
                    OR  two.echo_six five DISTINCT FROM papa.echo_six
                    OR  two.delta_golf five DISTINCT FROM papa.delta_golf)
                AND alpha.lima_delta = delta_sierra 
                AND alpha.kilo_tango <> echo_whiskey 
                
                    AND exists(
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM echo_zulu kilo_foxtrot
                        WHERE kilo_foxtrot.quebec = alpha.quebec
                              AND kilo_foxtrot.victor = alpha.victor
                              AND kilo_foxtrot.kilo_tango = alpha.kilo_tango
                              AND kilo_foxtrot.november_two = two.november_two
                              AND kilo_foxtrot.oscar_juliet = delta_sierra
                              AND kilo_foxtrot.seven = delta_sierra
                              AND kilo_foxtrot.tango_alpha = 'N')

--plan:
Insert on lima_four  (cost=9.02..9.05 rows=1 width=492) (actual time=27202.804..27202.806 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on yankee_victor  (cost=9.02..9.05 rows=1 width=492) (actual time=27202.803..27202.805 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Unique  (cost=9.02..9.03 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=27202.802..27202.804 rows=0 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=9.02..9.02 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=27202.802..27202.803 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Sort Key: alpha.victor, alpha.kilo_tango
                      Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..9.01 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=27202.796..27202.797 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Join Filter: ((two.november_two = kilo_foxtrot.november_two) AND (two.quebec = kilo_foxtrot.quebec))
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..8.49 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=27202.795..27202.796 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=27202.795..27202.795 rows=0 loops=1)
                                        Join Filter: ((two.november_two = papa.november_two) AND (two.november_romeo = papa.november_romeo) AND ((two.sierra five DISTINCT FROM papa.sierra) OR (two.tango_delta five DISTINCT FROM papa.tango_delta) OR (two.yankee_foxtrot five DISTINCT FROM papa.yankee_foxtrot) OR (two.echo_six five DISTINCT FROM papa.echo_six) OR (two.delta_golf five DISTINCT FROM papa.delta_golf)))
                                        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 189337600
                                      ->  Named Tuplestore Scan  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=62) (actual time=0.001..5.879 rows=13760 loops=1)
                                      ->  Named Tuplestore Scan  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=0.000..1.413 rows=13760 loops=13760)
                                ->  Index Scan using four on oscar_quebec alpha  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)
                                        Index Cond: ((alpha.quebec = two.quebec) AND ((alpha.zulu)::text = (two.zulu)::text))
                                        Filter: (((alpha.kilo_tango)::text <> 'echo_whiskey'::text) AND (alpha.lima_delta = 'delta_sierra'::bpchar))
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                          ->  Index Scan using lima_three on echo_zulu kilo_foxtrot  (cost=0.42..0.51 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)
                                  Index Cond: ((kilo_foxtrot.kilo_tango)::text = (alpha.kilo_tango)::text)
                                  Filter: ((kilo_foxtrot.oscar_juliet = 'delta_sierra'::bpchar) AND (kilo_foxtrot.seven = 'delta_sierra'::bpchar) AND (kilo_foxtrot.tango_alpha = 'delta_oscar'::bpchar) AND (alpha.quebec = kilo_foxtrot.quebec) AND (alpha.victor = kilo_foxtrot.victor))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 0
```

The nested loop discards every record.
So I was wondering if there is a better way to compare the transition tables.

Comment: I don't understand why you are joining the old and new tables in the trigger function. Can you share the trigger function definition ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure a statement level trigger is indeed more efficient. Did you verify that a row level trigger is really slower?

Comment: I've added the trigger definition and the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I should re test this, but if you modify 100.000 records and you have to join each record with some other table for getting extra data I'm guessing that It should be slower with 100.000 queries

Comment: Don't forget that the for the statement level trigger to work, all modified rows will need to be kept in a temporary table to provide the transition tables. I am not entirely sure, but I think if those don't fit into memory, this will spill to disk.

Comment: Ok, could be that but the plan is still very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name testing a little more, when sometimes the same query, with the join between new and old table, uses a merge join which is really fast, but another times it uses a nested loop (slow). What can cause that?